# If statement is or condition doesnt work?

Tags: coldfusion

The If statement doesn't work and still display the code between
, it works only when i have one condition.

```
 <cfif #GetCurrentUserDept.dept_id# neq 29 || #GetCurrentUserDept.dept_id# neq 40 >      
        code ....
</cfif>
```

Comment: What is the value of dept_id when you run this code?

Comment: @danbracuk right now its 40

Comment: What is your logic? Under what conditions would you like to execute `code`?

Comment: if i only leave it with 40 it will work and not show code

Comment: if dept_id equals 29 or 40 i would not like the code to show

Comment: Is GetCurrentUserDept a query?  If so, how many rows does it return?

Comment: But 29 does not equal 40.  That presents you with a dilemma.  You can change the or to an and, or follow Matt's suggestion.  It depends on your requirements which are becoming less clear as we go along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if `getCurrentUserDept.deptID` is 29 or 40 then the code will not display

```
<cfif NOT listFind('29,40', getCurrentUserDept.deptID)>
  code...
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider writing your if statement as follows:

```
<cfif NOT (GetCurrentUserDept.dept_id eq 29 OR GetCurrentUserDept.dept_id eq 40) >      
        code ....
</cfif>
```

Currently your code is equivalent to:

```
<cfif NOT (GetCurrentUserDept.dept_id eq 29 AND GetCurrentUserDept.dept_id eq 40) >      
        code ....
</cfif>
```

And we know that `GetCurrentUserDept.dept_id` cannot equal 40 and 29 at the same time. That's why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Care to explain the rationale for this suggestion?

Comment: The code executes if `dept_id` is `NOT` 29 or 40. Does that help?

Comment: There are simpler ways to express neither this nor that.  Matt's answer is one of them.